# Using geobytes web service to get cities list

Tags: web-services, web

I wanted a free web service to get cities list and found [geobytes](http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api.htm). Its good. I wanted to know What is the meaning of 50000 request? On every key pressed it makes a HTTP request.So do they count this way?

`but if you expect to be performing more than 50,000 requests per day (your average unique visitors X 5), then please tell us`

Anyone who has used this please help.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine what it means is that going over 50,000 requests can be penalized in someway. A key press is not a request - but entering a city and fetching that cities' details would constitute 1 of the 50,000 requests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but when you type any character it fetches matching list of cities as auto complete drop down, so will that be 1 request?

Comment: I've seen your reply a few days later. An auto complete drop down is the same as what we see with a google search or an ios safari search and I'm sure that until you click one of the choices then it will not be considered a request because the webpage doesn't populate all the boxes for the city until you actually physically click on one of the choices. Mousing over one of the choices for example doesn't populate the boxes you must click to do that and this is the request.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author and administrator of Goebytes'AutoCompleteCity API and there is now no practical limit to genuine use, and the reference to 50,000 lookup per day has been removed from the web site. I say practical, because it does have DOS attack prevention measures, but as the API is intended to be called from the browser (as opposed to a server - for that you would use the GetCityDetails API) its DOS protection measure of "1024 look ups per IP Address, per hour", should never cut in under any circumstances that I can imagine.